# How to extract an Array out of NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have been using an `NSDictionary` to store my `JSON` response. Now I tried to store them inside an array, so I can iterate over each values.

I used: `valueForKeyPath` and now each of those values are inside an `NSArray`.

The problem is instead of returning `self.myarray.count` (3), I only get (1). It wrote
the `NSDictionary` Keys into `myarray` at Index 0. So I have an Array inside `myarray` at Index 0 containing values (2,5,3).

Is there a way to quickly fix this and putting this like: index 0 : 2 , index 1: 5 , index 2: 3

and not index 0 : (2,5,3)?

Thanks I am still learning Obj-C.

Comment: Show the code and log of the data structure

Comment: I added valueForKeypath:@"@unionOfArrays... Now it does it automatically!! Thanks for the Post Coda. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you have perform something like following: `[self.myarray addObject: dict.keys];`

Use following instead: `self.myarray = dict.keys;`

If you do this only because you want to iterate over each value you could do the same with dictionary: `for(id key in dict)` or `for(id key in dict.keys)` iterates over each key. `for(id value in dict.values)` iterates over each value.